# Explain syntax of Oracle SQL where ('a','b') in (('x', 'y'))

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

In Oracle SQL this syntax is not accepted, returns `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

```
  select name
      from employees
     where (emp_id, dept_id) in (1 , 100)
        or (emp_id, dept_id) in (2, 200)
     order by emp_id;
```

While this syntax seems perfectly valid (Notice double parenthesis)

```
 select name
  from employees
 where (emp_id, dept_id) in ((1 , 100))
    or (emp_id, dept_id) in ((2, 200))
 order by emp_id;
```

Could you please explain why? I did not find any reference to this syntax in Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select name
from employees
where (emp_id, dept_id) in ((1, 100), (2, 200))
order by emp_id;
```

The issue is that you are comparing tuples.  Tuples need to be enclosed in their own parentheses.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could explain `((` syntax itself. Why this is not valid `where (emp_id, dept_id) in (1 , 100)
        or (emp_id, dept_id) in (2, 200)`

Comment: Thank you! I got it - tuples!

Comment: @joe.d - The syntax is not `((`. Tuples are surrounded by a single pair of parentheses - one for each tuple. Then the "things" on the right of the `IN` operator must be enclosed in parentheses. Think of it as `( (1,100) )` as similar to `( (1,100), (2,200), (5,500) )`. The first `(` and last `)` enclose the values used in the `IN` conditions. Those values happen to be tuples, each in its own parentheses. The disappointment in this regard is that Oracle does not implement `(emp_id, dept_id) = (1, 100)`, equality of tuples; you must hack it with the `IN` condition.

Comment: @mathguy Thank you very much for comprehensive explanation.